# TypeScript type narrowing not working for union type

Tags: typescript

Why is type narrowing not working in these snippets?

```
const xyz: { num: number } | { str: string }
if ("num" in xyz) {
    xyz // { num: number; } | { str: string; }
}
```

I even tried adding a type discriminant:

```
const xyz: { type: "num", num: number } | { type: "str", str: string }
if (xyz.type === "num") {
    xyz // { type: "num", num: number } | { type: "str", str: string }
}
```

I'm using Typescript version 5.0.2

Comment: it's strange, for me it works [here](https://tsplay.dev/N95P9N)

Comment: Oh OK, it seems when it complains about using a variable that's not yet initialized, then it's not able to properly do the type narrowing

Comment: Let's close the question then

Comment: Would this not be useful information for someone to know?

Comment: @prmph   Your first example works fine, so what information are you saying is useful for others. ?

Comment: In my opinion this is an important question and answer, and should not be closed. It took me many minutes to figure out that a soft errors (really a warning) detected by the type-checker can throw off type narrowing. The first example was also nt working for me because of some code in the same file before those lines which did not appear to be related. Maybe I can create a repro.

Comment: @prmph   I wouldn't say not assigning to a const is a soft error.   But yes, what I would say in TS fix the errors in order they appear, Code Insight in VS Code is not great when you have TS errors.

Comment: Well then, it can be closed

Comment: @prmph  To be fair, your maybe right about keeping open.  It's just maybe an answer that explains TS Errors effecting VS Code insight might be a good answer.  You could answer this, and I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems when the Typescript type-checker complains about prior errors or warnings, then that can throw off proper type narrowing.

In my case, the solution was to fix (or silence) the use of the un-initialized variable `xyz` (and other prior type errors), and type narrowing worked properly again.

TL;DR Seemingly unrelated type errors can put the type-checker in a bad state; Ensure simple errors are fixed first before tackling any weird errors.

Comment: Maybe you should fix up your question so it gives context to this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Type narrowing is not working in your examples because the type union of `{ num: number } | { str: string } and { type: "num", num: number } | { type: "str", str: string }` are not mutually exclusive, meaning that a variable of this type can have a property that belongs to both union members.

In the first example, even though you checked that "num" in xyz, xyz can still be of type `{ str: string }`. This is because xyz can have the property str: string which is a member of the second union member.

Similarly, in the second example, checking `xyz.type === "num"` only narrows down the type to `{ type: "num", num: number } | { type: "str", str: string }`, but not to a specific type. Therefore, xyz can still have the property `str: string`.

To make type narrowing work in these examples, you need to use a type guard that can narrow down the type to a specific member of the union. For example, you can define a custom type guard function like this:

```
function isNum(obj: { num?: unknown }): obj is { num: number } {
  return typeof obj.num === "number";
}
```

Then you can use this type guard in your code to narrow down the type of xyz:

```
const xyz: { num: number } | { str: string } = { num: 42 };
if (isNum(xyz)) {
  xyz // { num: number }
}
```

Similarly, for the second example, you can define a type guard function like this:

```
function isNum(obj: { type?: unknown }): obj is { type: "num", num: number } {
  return obj.type === "num";
}
```

Then you can use this type guard in your code to narrow down the type of xyz:

```
const xyz: { type: "num", num: number } | { type: "str", str: string } = { type: "num", num: 42 };
if (isNum(xyz)) {
  xyz // { type: "num", num: number }
}
```

Comment: No, you are incorrect. If xyz has the property "num", then it cannot have the property "str"; that is how disjoint unions work. FYI, the problem was simply that the type-checker complained about another error, and that seems to have disabled the type narrowing.